# Condition with left join table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have Quiz table which is shown in image.[image: quiz table]

and quiz result history table like[image: user_quiz_results table]

I write left join query between these two table.
My query is like:

```
  select q.*
       , c.name as catname 
       , qrh.q_complete
       , q s.test_type
       , qs.questionid
       , sum(qrh.score) as score1
       , sum(qrh.total_questions) as tot_que 
    from categories c
       , quiz q 
    left 
    join user_quiz_results_history qrh 
      on qrh.quiz_id = q.quizid 
    left 
    join quizquestions qq 
      on qq.quizid = q.quizid 
    left
    join questions qs 
      on qs.subcatid = qq.subjectid 
   where c.catid = q.catid 
     AND q.catid = 1
     AND q.status = 'Active' 
     AND q.enddate >= '2016-05-02' 
   group 
        by q.quizid
```

This query give result all quiz table data and related user_quiz_results table.

If I write query using condition for left join table like userid=90, I don't get the any of data.

I want all data of quiz and if table have result for userid=90 get data from table user_quiz_history.avg(score).

Comment: Please post text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Include the condition in the respective ON clause

Comment: add table schema with some sample data, it will help others to understand your situation quickly.

Comment: ... And don't mix implicit (comma) and explicit join styles. Better yet, don't use comma join at all

Comment: I Write query  and I get only one quiz record which have userid 84 in user_quiz_result_history table and I want all quiz data from quiz table => select q.*
       , qrh.q_complete
       , sum(qrh.score) as score1
       , sum(qrh.total_questions) as tot_que 
    from categories c
       , quiz q 
    left 
    join user_quiz_results_history qrh 
      on qrh.quiz_id = q.quizid 
    
   where qrh.userid=84
     AND q.catid = 1
     AND q.status = 'Active' 
     AND q.enddate >= '2016-05-02' 
   group 
        by q.quizid

Answer (score 0):

Write condition on left join clause.

```
select q.* , qrh.q_complete , sum(qrh.score) as score1 , sum(qrh.total_questions) as tot_que from categories c , quiz q left join user_quiz_results_history qrh on qrh.quiz_id = q.quizid AND qrh.userid=84 where  q.catid = 1 AND q.status = 'Active' AND q.enddate >= '2016-05-02' group by q.quizid
```